# Laravel: text-overflow:ellipsis does not work with displaying unescaped data

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm having a problem with the property `text-overflow:ellipsis`.

In particular, the three points at the end of the broken line are not displayed.

Since I don't want to escape the data, since I use ckeditor (hence formatted text), I use the following wording

`{!! $treatment->description !!}`

for the Description column only.

This is my code:

```
<table id="tabledata" class="table table-striped hover" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Stay</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($treatments as $treatment)
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="p-4">{{ $treatment->title }}</td>
                    <td class="p-4"><span class="descresize">{!! $treatment->description !!}</span></td>
                    <td class="p-4">{{ $treatment->duration }} </td>
                    <td class="p-4">{{ $treatment->price }} €</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('treatment.edit', compact('treatment'))}}" role="button">Update</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

CSS

```
.descresize{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;    
}
```

Can you kindly help me? I am going crazy to solve this problem

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74310029/edit) to show what `$treatment->description` is? If you're applying the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to the wrapping `<span>` element, and `$treatment->description` contains HTML elements (since `{!! !!}` is often used to output HTML from a string), it might not be applying. I'm not a CSS expert, but you might need to apply that `text-overflow` property to something like `.descresize > div > span` (or something similar).

Comment: @TimLewis is a text with p and/or bold tags that is retrieved by ckeditor like this: <p> The preoperative visit allows the surgeon to evaluate the size, shape and possible modifications of the breast and to agree with the patient the type of surgery and prosthesis . </p>

Comment: Right, CKEditor would do that. So yeah, if you inspect the element via your browser (right-click > Inspect element), you can see the CSS that is being applied. If you manually add those `overflow`, `text-overflow`, etc. properties to the rendered `<p>` element does it work? If so, your CSS should be `.descresize > p { ... }` 

Comment: @TimLewis perfect, solved with your last answer. If you want to put it in the post it will be evaluated as the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel's Blade Templating engine, `{!! !!}` is used to output unescaped content, including (and not limited to) HTML tags. When combined with CKEditor, you typically get things like this:

```
<span class="descresize">{!! $treatment->description !!}</span>
<!-- <span class="descresize"><p>Something something long description of the associated Treatment</p></span> -->
```

Since the CSS properties are being assigned to `<span class="descresize">`, which now equates to `<span class="descresize"><p>...</p></span>`, the properties may or may not propagate to these nested HTML elements.

If the content of `{!! $treatment->description !!}` is going to be consistent (i.e. always a `<p>...</p>` element), you can simply modify the CSS to point at this nested element:

```
.descresize > p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;    
}
```

Since the `<p>` tag only contains text, and no nested elements, this should handle the properties correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarity given